# Material-UI align elements in the center

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Kinda dumb question, but this is a thing I struggle the most with. I have three Textfields with descriptions, this is kinda login form. What I struggle with is that I want these three textfields to be aligned. The only way I can achieve this right now is adding `justify="flex-end"` to all `Grid container`s. Textfields will align right, but will leave the center of the screen. I need them to be aligned and in the center.

I know I'm doing something wrong, not sure that such monstrosity of grid containers and items is needed at all for such a simple task

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/relaxed-banach-lz5dr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={1}
        direction="row"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        <Grid item>
          <Typography>Input1</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            id="input1-textfield"
            margin="dense"
            value="TEST1"
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={1}
        direction="row"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        <Grid item>
          <Typography>Input2Input2Input2</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField variant="outlined" id="input1-textfield" margin="dense" />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={1}
        direction="row"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        <Grid item>
          <Typography>Input3Input3</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField variant="outlined" id="input1-textfield" margin="dense" />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The Textfields look like they're center-aligned in the codesandbox you provided.

Comment: @Y.S. I need them to be aligned with each other, not just stay in center